# Recyclerview with databinding does not detect onClick action

Tags: java, android, mvvm, data-binding, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a small project where I'm trying to implement MVVM with databinding to an application that already exist and I got stuck on the onClick event. Basically the method I'm trying to call in ViewModel is being highlighted yellow so the binding is in place (that would be the `"onCLickS"` method). The `@BindingAdapter` I have placed in ViewModel to check the binding also works fine.

I've tried to put the `android:onClick` basically everywhere in the layout and it didn't work. Already tried everything i was able to find on the net.

Databinding is enabled in Gradle.
Main Activity with recyclerview:

```
public class MainListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MainListAdapter myAdapter;
private MainListViewModel mainListViewModel;
private List<MainListModel> myGridList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ActivityMainListBinding binding;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

    binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main_list);
    mainListViewModel = new MainListViewModel();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    myGridList = mainListViewModel.passGridList();

    myAdapter = new MainListAdapter(myGridList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    binding.setViewModel(mainListViewModel);
    binding.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
}
```

Activity with my row item:

```
public class MainListItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MainListViewModel mainListViewModel;
private MainListItemBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

    binding= DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_list_item);
    mainListViewModel = new MainListViewModel();

    binding.setViewModel(mainListViewModel);


    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainListViewModel extends BaseObservable{

    private final ObservableField<String> text;
//    private final Context context;
    public ObservableArrayList<MainListModel> gridList;
    iMainListItems iMainListItems;


    private static final String TAG = "MainListViewModel";

    public MainListViewModel(){

        text = new ObservableField<String>();
        gridList = new ObservableArrayList<MainListModel>();
//        this.context = context;
        this.iMainListItems = iMainListItems;

    }

    @BindingAdapter({"android:newActivity"})
    public static void lounchNewActivity(View view, String category) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LinkListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("category",category);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
    public List<MainListModel> passGridList(){

        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.books, "Books"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.business,  "Business"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.cinema, "Cinema"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.politics,  "Politics"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.technology,  "Technology"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.gaming,  "Gaming"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.cooking,  "Cooking"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.datascience,  "Data Science"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.design,  "Design"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.diy,  "DIY"));
        gridList.add(new MainListModel(R.drawable.sports,  "Sports"));

        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.model);

        return gridList;

    }

    public  void onClickL(){

        Log.e(TAG,"Long Clicked!!!!!!!!!!!1");

    }

    public  void onClickS(View view,String category){


        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LinkListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("category",category);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        Log.d(TAG,"Clicked!!!!!!");

    }

}
```

Row item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name= "model"
            type = "com.example.psotor.zbiq.models.MainListModel"/>
        <variable
            name= "viewModel"
            type = "com.example.psotor.zbiq.viewmodels.MainListViewModel"/>
    </data>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:paddingTop="26dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"

                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryFade"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:elevation="2dp"
                        android:text="@{model.categoryName}"
                        android:id="@+id/gridName"

                        />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/gridImage"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:src="@{model.categoryImage}"
                        android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onClickS(v,model.categoryName)}"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                    />
                </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Adapter:

```
public class MainListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainListViewHolder> {


    private List<MainListModel> gridList;


    public MainListAdapter(List<MainListModel> gridList) {
        this.gridList = gridList;
    }

    @Override
    public MainListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        MainListItemBinding binding = MainListItemBinding.inflate(inflater,parent,false);
        return new MainListViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainListViewHolder holder,int position) {

        final MainListModel mainListModel = gridList.get(position);
        holder.bind(mainListModel);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return (null != gridList ? gridList.size() : 0);
    }
    @BindingAdapter({"android:src"})
    public static void setImageViewResource(ImageView imageView, int resource) {
        Picasso.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(resource)
                .centerCrop()
                .resize(500,500)
                .into(imageView);
    }

}
```

ViewHolder:

```
public class MainListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    private final MainListItemBinding mBinding;

    public MainListViewHolder(MainListItemBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.mBinding = binding;

    }
    public void bind (MainListModel mainListModel){
        mBinding.setModel(mainListModel);
        mBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug your databinding.

- Enable databinding debugging in Android Studio

  - Open Settings > Editor > Data Binding > "Reference code generated by the compiler
- Build the project.
- Open your layout's data binding file (should be something like `MainListItemBinding`)
- Find the `onClickS` method call
- Put a breakpoint there and at the top of the method in which it lives (something like `_internalCallbackOnClick`
- Debug the app and wait for the top breakpoint to get hit, then step through to the point where your method should be called.

If you still can't figure it out, post your findings from this debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! It turned out that my ViewModel was `null` in the binding because I've put the `binding.setViewModel(mainListViewModel)` in the `onCreate` of the row item which was never called.  Moving to viewHolder fixed the issue.